# is there a way to pass a variable to modal using a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

here is my link and the sample data value i want to pass "data-id"

```
<a href="#edit_task" data-toggle="modal" data-id="WAH"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg fa-fw"></i></a>
```

javascript code to load the modal and assign the data value to the modal

```
<script>
       $("#openModal").click(function(){
$(".modal-body").text($(this).data("id"));
$("#edit_task").modal("open");
});
       </script>
```

my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_task">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
<form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">add new user</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
```

modal body i would like to display the modal variable here

```
 <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        

  </div>
```

modal footer

```
 <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <?php
  echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='edit' onclick='return mess()'; >";echo "save"; echo "</button>";
       ?>
 </div>
```

function to confirm when a value is saved

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function mess(){
  alert ("the new user is successfully saved");
  return true;
}

</script>
```

end of the modal

```
</form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmkxwu7r/) of what you are looking for.

I changed your Wah button, replacing the href attribute with a data-target attribute:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_task" data-id="Wah">Wah</a>
```

Note: If you want the button to look like a link then replace the btn-primary class I used in the example with btn-link

Instead of using a click event on a button, use [bootstraps show.bs.modal event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events).  The `$(event.relatedTarget)` syntax is how you can get the button object for the button that was clicked to open the modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#edit_task').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {        
      $('#edit_task').find('.modal-body').text($(event.relatedTarget).data('id'));
  })


});
```

Comment: and how do i display the data on the modal

Comment: This line is how you display the data in the modal as demonstrated in the working fiddle that I linked in my answer. `$('#edit_task').find('.modal-body').text($(event.relatedTarget).data('id'));`

Comment: What do you mean, "echo the data"?  Do you mean interpolating some PHP variable value into the data-id attribute value in HTML, eg: `data-id="<?php echo somePhpVariableThatIHaveNoClueAboutBecauseYouDontShowAnyPhpCodeStructureInYourQuestion ?>"` ??